# How can I add date end of the exported file's name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm using jQuery for Export HTML table to Excel like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ExcExport").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //getting data from our table
            var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
            var table_div = document.getElementById('divTableDataHolder');
            var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
            a.download =  'UkomeRapor'+ '.xls';
            a.click();
        });
    });
```

output is `UkomeRapor.xls` but I want like add time end of the file name like `UkomeRapor2112017.xls`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do,

```
var today = new Date();
a.download =  'UkomeRapor'+ 
today.getDate().toString()+(today.getMonth()+1)+today.getFullYear()
+ '.xls';
```

Also, this is pure Javascript question.

Answer (score 3):

You can get current date using new date and split the date value to append in file name.

```
var d = new Date();
var datestring = d.getDate()  + (d.getMonth()+1) +  d.getFullYear() ,
a.download = 'UkomeRapor' + datestring + '.xls';
```